# Evaluating limit involving convergent and divergent hypergeometric functions

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers satisfying $c - a - b = 1 > 0$. After much manipulation, my problem reduces to evaluating the following limit:
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 1^-} \left| \frac{1}{_2F_1(a,b,c;z) -\ _2F_1'(a,b,c;z)\sqrt{1-z}} \right|.
$$
Here, a prime is a derivative with respect to $z$.

Now, we can use Euler's integral representation of Gauss' hypergeometric function to show 
$$
_2F'_1(a,b,c;z) = \frac{ab}{c}\ _2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z).
$$
Thus, while $_2F_1(a,b,c;1)$ converges by Gauss' hypergeometric theorem ($c - a - b > 0$), its derivative evaluated at $z=1$ diverges because $c + 1 - (a+1) - (b+1) = 0 \not> 0$. This is where I get stuck. I don't know how to deal with the denominator in this limit. I have a feeling this is quite obvious, but I can't see what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singularity of $\ _2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z)$ at $z=1$ in your conditions is only logarithmical [see, for example, the [Euler's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type)] so $\sqrt{1-z}$ kills the contribution of the second term in the numerator to the limiting value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, I'm struggling to see the logarithmic divergence. Do you mind elaborating on your answer? I tried writing $z = 1 - \epsilon,$ where $\epsilon \ll 1$ and evaluating the integral. Is there a better approach to see it?

Comment: According to Euler's formula $$\ _2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z) = \frac{1}{\beta(b+1,a+1)}\int_0^1 x^b (1-x)^a (1-x+x\epsilon)^{-1-a}dx.$$ At small $\epsilon$, the integral which is coming from $x\approx 1$ can be evaluated as follows
$$\ _2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z) \approx \frac{1}{\beta(b+1,a+1)}\int_0^1 (1-x+x\epsilon)^{-1}dx\approx \frac{1}{\beta(b+1,a+1)}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$